# How to delete first line of a file if it does not contain a specified string?

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have files that look like this:

```
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
```

But some are malformed and have the incorrect first line like this:

```
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
```

I need a one liner that will delete the first line if it does not contain `username`

i tried it with sed but it does not work:

```
sed -e '1!b' -e '/username/!d'
```

Comment: The sed command you gave should work. Can you check with `xxd` or similar whether the input file contains some invisible characters?

Comment: What you have should work.  You could also write it `sed -e '1{ /username/!d; }'`, but clearly something else is happening.

Comment: or you want `sed -i`?

Comment: yes there was invisible characters from preventing the original sed from working, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print if 1 != $. || /username/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 || /username/' file
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
username
Total 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to do this using `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 && $0 != "username" {next} 1' file
```